# Does the isothermal compressibility diverge at the lambda line in Helium-4?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, phase-transition, critical-phenomena, superfluidity

Helium-4 has a normal-superfluid phase transition which corresponds to the lambda line in the P-T diagram. The heat capacity at constant pressure $C_p$ shows a discontinuity when the lambda line is crossed. From universal scaling, the susceptibility associated with the order parameter has a divergence at the critical temperature, which can be any of the lambda line. In this case the susceptibility is not a physical quantity.

I read [here](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.8.530) it is known that the isothermal compressibility diverges at the lambda line but I don't see directly why. Does it have a critical exponent? Looking at the tables [here](https://cds.cern.ch/record/1444601/files/978-1-4419-9979-5_BookBackMatter.pdf), like in page 437, I thought the isothermal compressibility doesn't diverge. If the heat capacity at constant volume is $C_v \neq C_p$, by the relation between them,
$$
C_p-C_V= -T \alpha^2 VT /\kappa,
$$
where $\alpha$ is the coefficient of thermal expansion and $\kappa$ the isothermal compressibility, then $\kappa$ doesn't diverge. Unless $\alpha$ diverges in such a way to make $\alpha^2 / \kappa < \infty$.

I would appreciate if you could give me some references. Thank you in advance.